# if-else change bg color depending what is the letter in the div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a crossword puzzle and so I got to the point of having to create conditions ...

I have not found anything that solves my problem

I need a code that when in the input text I put the right letter set bg color "green" and if it is wrong in "red"

```
<input class="empty" type="text" id="names01" onchange="changeColor()" maxlength="1" />
```

//for example if names01 = "c" set bg color green.....else set bg color to red

```
if (condition){function changeColor() {
document.getElementById("names01").style.backgroundColor = "green";}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Also you want `function changeColor(id) { if (condition){
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";}}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is ambiguous. You should regard what [tag:javascript] code you have tried or at least what the logic or algorithm you hav adopted to solve the problem?

Comment: ok..
the condition is what I need ... I have no idea what to put after the "if"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the condition inside the function to match the value and change the color:

```js
function changeColor(e) {
  let bgColor = e.value === 'c' ? 'green' : 'red';
  document.getElementById("names01").style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

```html
<input class="empty" type="text" id="names01" onchange="changeColor(this)" maxlength="1" />
```

Since, you are passing the reference of the element in the change function you can also use:

```
function changeColor(e) {
  let bgColor = e.value === 'c' ? 'green' : 'red';
  e.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

Comment: @green9975 This should works. You can use `onkeyup` instead of `onchange` to get bg change immediately after input character "c".

Comment: @thanhdx Thanks for the suggestion but that may not be the requirement for the OP since he wants `onchange`

Comment: i would use `oninput `

Comment: Also add condition for "else set bg color to red".

Comment: Now it is red if empty.

Comment: @mplungjan OP says `//for example if names01 = "c" set bg color green.....else set bg color to red` which means else has everything that is other than `c`. There is no specific cases mentioned by OP for `else`.

Comment: _I put the right letter set bg color "green" and if it is wrong in "red"_ So no letter is neither red nor green

Answer (score 0):

The immediate change is to have the condition inside the function and pass the ID to it

```
function changeColor(id) { 
 if (condition) { 
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
 }
}
```

You likely want this abstraction. Otherwise you need a lot of conditions

Note I delegate from the container instead of adding an event handler on each field

Also I use "input" instead of "change" since it handles more cases (for example paste)

```js
const solution = {
  "names01": "c",
  "names02": "r"
}


document.getElementById("crosswordContainer").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.type==="text") {
    // conditions
    let myClass = ""; // the word class is reserved
    const val = tgt.value.trim().toLowerCase(); // remove spaces
    tgt.classList.remove("red", "green"); // reset
    if (val) { // something was filled in
      myClass = val === solution[tgt.id] ? "green" : "red"; // this is called a ternary condition
      tgt.classList.add(myClass); // check if myClass is empty, if not, add it
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="crosswordContainer">
  <input class="empty" type="text" id="names01" maxlength="1" /> 
  <input class="empty" type="text" id="names02" maxlength="1" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: he is a beginner hes not gonna understand your code

Comment: So it deserves a downvote when I try to educate in using recommended practices? Very strange!

Comment: i didnt down vote i will upvote for you, and your right this answer is not for him its for whoever has the same questions.

Comment: Since the question is very poorly formulated and shows a lack of fundamental knowledge, it is not really useful for others

Comment: me and hannon are students at the same collage, i dont have explain myself to anyone.

Comment: @milabrice but that is a good explanation. Anyway I updated the answer to handle red AND green AND empty